# izimodal why under the footer

Tags: javascript, izimodal

I'm doing a project with codeigniter. But the izimodal appears under the footer and encounters the following error

```
VM11645 iziModal.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at VM11645 iziModal.js:23
    at VM11645 iziModal.js:25
```

Error is: https://prnt.sc/v7havm

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/js/iziModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You need to add jQuery link js before iziModal.js if you use cdn.